# std::stol corrupts stack on failure

Tags: c++, constructor, stdstring

class.h

```
// class.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class TV {
public:
  TV() {}
  TV(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string);

private:
  int member;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
//main.cpp
#include "class.h"    

TV::TV(std::string a, std::string b, std::string c, std::string d, std::string e) {
  try {
    member = std::stol(a);
    if (member <= 0)
      throw;
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Invalid argument" << std::endl;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  new TV("TEST","NAME","0.1","0.1","0.1");
};
```

So it turns out that if I provided std::stol with an invalid_argument, then in gdb all other arguments passed to the function would appear corrupted.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Does doing a clean compile (e.g. "make clean; make") help?  If not, you might try temporarily renaming the SubclassC class to some other name and see if it makes a difference; there might be a namespace collision somewhere that is confusing the compiler.

Comment: "Again, sorry that this isn't reproducible a meaningful way" Please elaborate. Are you saying that if you tried the same thing with an [mcve] then you cannot reproduce the error? If so, then the code you've shown is not the problem.

Comment: I have been using make clean; make. After enough rebuilds, I went through and manually deleted all object files and binaries, just to make sure I didn't have a bug in the Makefile and was debugging stale code. Namespace collision is a great idea! Will check that!

Comment: AndyG, I'm very confident there isn't anything wrong with this block of code itself. I'm passing strings by value in the simplest way I know how and I have analogous code that calls a similar constructor in an identical way that works fine. I just don't know what other bugs a program might have that could cause this behavior so deterministically (stack corruption/heap corruption).

Comment: You are converting the vector at `args[1]` to `std::string arg1`, is that conversion right?
`args[1]` returns a reference and don't check for bounds... `<Address 0x7ffffffff000 out of bounds>` [std::vector::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the issue. But it's a problem even with hardcoded strings. new subclassA("test", "test", "test")

Comment: Does your actual implementation use the "return" keyword in createSubclass or does it just call "new" and never do anything with the new value?  If your compiler allows that code to compile, then the result is probably set to an invalid pointer that points somewhere random in memory.  Otherwise, you haven't provided nearly enough code, since you left out the return keywords as well as the return type, and who knows what else.

Comment: As your question stands, it shows some code that works and then vaguely states that a different version of it doesn't work. You should *really* show the code that doesn't work rather than just the one that does.

Comment: That's fair guys. I need to make a compilable, small example. Working on it.